# How to extract F2FS file system based disk img files?

Tags: android-source, ext4

I am writing a program in windows (C#) to extract disk images from [AOSP](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/partitions-images). I am using [simg2img](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/aa45cb8/libsparse/simg2img.c), but to no avail. Simg2img only supports EXT4 based file systems and some of my IMG files are written in [F2FS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/f2fs.txt). How do I extract these files? I have been struck with this problem for weeks if anyone can give any direction it would be helpful!